# Regular expression : numbers with nine digits

Tags: c#

it is possible to control if string Number has 9 digits?

```
String Number;
if()
{
//9 digits
}
```

Have you any idea? Thanks.

Comment: what you want to ask?

Comment: What do you mean by 'has nine digits'? A minimum of nine? Maximum? Exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  if (Regex.IsMatch(Number,@"\d{9}"))
   {
         //Has 9 digits      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Number;

if (Regex.Match(number, "\d{9}"))
{
    // Number has 9 digits
}

if (Regex.Match(number, "^\d{9}$"))
{
    // Number is 9 digits only
}
```